# Why does using a nested url with the Meteor.Router prevent template from rendering?

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor's router package and everything works fine when I try to render the `groupCreate` template under the `/createGroup` URL like this:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  "/createGroup": {
    to: "groupCreate",
    and: function() {
       return Session.set("currentGroupId", null);
    }
  }
});
```

However, the template is not drawn when I try to use a nested URL like `/groups/create` instead of `/createGroup`. I would like to understand why. Do nested URLs carry a special semantic?

Comment: Nested routes work fine for me. The issue may be elsewhere in your code like a misbehaving filter or something.

Comment: The template is not mentioned in any filter. And as I said, the *only* change I do is: I change the URL from `createGroup` to `groups/create`.

Comment: Meteor.Router is deprecated. The standard router packages is now IronRouter.